# Update column with incremental values when the condition holds

Tags: mysql

Given an ***invoice*** table with the following ***id***, ***number***, ***year*** columns.
How to update the number column with incremental values for the specific
financial ***year***?

```
 |  id  | number | year |
 |   1  |      1 | 2019 |
 |   2  |      2 | 2019 |
 |   3  |      3 | 2019 |
 |   4  |      1 | 2020 |
 |   5  |      2 | 2020 |
 |   6  |      3 | 2020 |
 |   7  |      4 | 2020 |
 |   8  |      1 | 2021 |
```

***Update***

Would be nice to have a query with condition because here for simplicity I wrote a year but actually it's a date yyyy-mm-dd and I want to increment the number column value for each fiscal year that starts from July 1st and ends in June 30

***Answer***

This is what worked for me the best

```
UPDATE invoice,
(SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS rowNumber, id FROM invoice, (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS rn WHERE year = 2020 ) as t 
SET invoice.number = t.rowNumber 
WHERE t.id = invoice.id
```

Comment: Use this: SET number = number + 1.

Comment: what is your mysql version

Comment: mysql 5.7
what you mean by SET number = number + 1 ?
update invoice SET number = number + 1 where year = 2020 ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use window function -  `row_number()` if your MySQL version is 8+

```
UPDATE invoice
        INNER JOIN
    (select *, row_number() over(partition by year order by id) as number from invoice) i ON invoice.id= i.id
SET 
    invoice.number = i.number
```

Comment: Actually in my case the ***year*** column is a date yyyy-mm-dd, I wrote yyyy for the simplicity and the financial year starts from July 1st and ends in June 30, That's why I specified in the title of the question "when the condition holds"

Comment: @ԱրաՄարտիրոսյան update your question clearly - specify what you exactly need